# Insufficient permissions to user for create/delete term

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, term-store

I have created child term inside selected term from code behind. Now when I try to delete or create term with same user then I got "`The current user has insufficient permissions to perform this operation.`" error.

Previously it was work but currently it is not working. I have given "**Term Store Administrators**" permission to my current user. I have written same code as I have written for at the time of creating new page.

My code block (I'm getting exception in term creation line):

```
        try
        {
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession(sitecollection);
                TermStore termStore = session.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"];
                Group group = termStore.Groups["GroupName"];
                TermSet sTermSet = group.TermSets["S"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hdnAllSelectedTermGuiIds.Value))
                    {
                        string[] newTerms = hdnAllSelectedTermGuiIds.Value.TrimEnd(',').Split(',');

                        for (int i = 0; i < newTerms.Length; i++)
                        {
                                try
                                {
                                    Guid termId = new Guid(newTerms[i]);
                                    Term termObj = structureTermSet.GetTerm(termId);
                                    Term newTerm = termObj.CreateTerm(hdnPageName.Value, langCode);
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex2)
                                {

                                }
                        }
                        sTermSet.TermStore.CommitAll();
                    }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Are you executing the code with elevated privileges?

Comment: I have tried with both run with elevated privileges and without privileges but not working.

Comment: please post your code and the full exception being thrown. do you know which line is throwing the error?

Comment: I have attached code....I'm getting error when try to create term. same code is for delete term also.

Comment: I think this issue is of page layout. Because when I have tried with application page, it works. but it is not working in page layout.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure user had right permission, check at two places.

1. Central admin -> Manage service application -> Managed meta data
   service - and the are on the page is call Term store Administrators
2. The next place to check is to highlight your Manage metadata service
   which is located Central admin -> Manage service application and
   click on permissions on the ribbon and make sure the users your
   running the code with has the correct access

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956405/the-current-user-has-insufficient-permissions-to-perform-this-operation-add-ter

Comment: I have already given permissions to both place. still not working.